# Is it possible in Python to create a class which duplicates the functionality of some class, but changes it's base class?

Tags: python

The original class structure looks like this:

```
class PyLibMCCache(BaseMemcachedCache):
class BaseMemcachedCache(BaseCache):
```

I have created a class with additional functionality called `BaseTagsMemcachedCache` which derives from `BaseMemcachedCache`, like that:

```
class BaseTagsMemcachedCache(BaseMemcachedCache):
```

Is it possible to create new class which will be the same as the `PyLibMCCache` (eg. with same methods and attributes), but with `BaseTagsMemcachedCache` as its base class? I am using Mixin (`BaseTagsCacheMixin`) as a workaround, but I think there might be a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new type with the same attributes but a different base class like this:

```
PyLibMCTagsCache = type("PyLibMCTagsCache", 
                        (BaseTagsMemcachedCache,),
                        vars(PyLibMCCache))
```

This seems rather convoluted to me, though.  I'd probably go for some more straight-forward design.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about [multiple inheritance](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#multiple-inheritance)? Yes, you can define:

```
class NewBaseTagsMemcachedCache(BaseTagsMemcachedCache, PyLibMCCache):
```

Keep in mind, that left-to-right rule applies in Python.

Comment: @NiklasB. And what do you think this link I gave is for?

Answer (score 1):

Python classes can have multiple inheritance. Will that do it for you?

Comment: I am using it right now, this is what I meant with the Mixin (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin) Thanks anyway

Comment: I think you're already doing it the right way. Are you looking for an alternative that would solve some problem you have now?

Comment: All the classes I want to add functionality to (`MemcachedCache`, `PyLibMCCache`) are derived from `BaseMemcachedCache`. I can't change the `__init__` in the Mixin class easily, because the classes accept different number of parameters, so I was looking for a solution with changing the base class

Comment: If the parent classes have incompatible initializers, I would think that changing the mixin class's `__init__` is exactly what you want to do: It must explicitly call the inits for the parent classes anyway, so just call them correctly.

Comment: But check if "Abstract Base Classes" do anything you are interested in.